# Image Caching With Anroid Libraries

Tags: android, kotlin, coil

My app is getting a list of movie objects, which includes a movie poster url, and it's displaying those posters and titles, then when a user clicks on that movie, it goes to a movie detail activity, that also has the poster and title, along with some more info.  Pretty simple.  I've noticed though that when I click the movie, there's still a second or two where the poster hasn't loaded, and I'd like to eliminate that, which seems relatively easy with caching.  I was using Picasso, I recently switched to Coil for image loading, and they both claim to handle caching behind the scenes, but I'm assuming that isn't happening because of this loading time.  In both activities I'm just loading it with:

```
posterImageView.load(it.posterURL ?: {url of "no poster found" image})
```

Is there anything extra I need to be doing in order to be loading these from cache instead of loading the image from url every time?

Comment: 1) are you using the same URL in both cases?
2) both image layouts have the same size?
3) what happens if you turn air plane mode?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap) you should use [LruCache](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache) as defined in here. But there is also a way around:

For storing a large number of images you should first create a temporary folder that can only be accessed by your application (usually inside data/data/package_name/) and then save every image you download for the first time in that folder giving the **key** as the name of the image. After that whenever you need to show the image just use the " if " condition to check if the image for that particular key (the name from which you saved the image) is stored or not. If it is then show the image. (Just remember to clear the folder images another time the app is opened).